# How to get current base url in register route class?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, nopcommerce-4.1

I'm developing plugin for nopcommerce shopping cart(ASP.NET Core 2.1).
Before registering routes in RouteProvider class,i need to access current domain name in order to some validation checks but when using IHttpContextAccessor to get Httpcontext and get current domain, Httpcontext is null.

Is there any solution to access current domain name in route provider class?

```
 public void RegisterRoutes(IRouteBuilder routes)
 {
    var httpContextAccessor = EngineContext.Current.Resolve<IHttpContextAccessor>();
    var domainName = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Host.Value.ToString();

    var pluginValidtyChecker = new PluginValidityChecker.ValidityChecker();
    if (pluginValidtyChecker.CheckIsValid(domainName))
    {

     //Register routes

    }
 }
```

In the application developed by me users first enter the domain name the plugin should work on and then buy plugin.After purchasing we generate a license key that's mapped with domain name and users must be entered this license key in plugin settings.
Because plugin override some main route of nopcommerce i need first check that license key and domain name that's plugin currently work on, is valid or not. 
This route must be registered on compile time.

Comment: If you want the current HttpContext, there are many ways to get them. One of the easiest would be dependency-injection.

Comment: I,m using dependency injection  for inject IHttpContextAccessor but _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext is null

Comment: Could you add the code, where you want to use the Url/HttpContext and in which class it is? So the accessor is not null?

Comment: Accessor inject successfully and not null but HttpContext property is null

Comment: I don't think that `HttpContext` is available at this point. RegisterRoutes is called at the start of the application. There is no request exist at that point. Are you registering routes at runtime?

Comment: No.It's register on application start.I think like you that there isn't any way to get it this point .I should using another solution to solve my problem

Comment: You could use Environment-Variables to define valid base-Url.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more? What do you mean by the current domain? The routes are for your application, so you would know the domain which you can read from the configuration file

Comment: The question was updated.Please check it again

Comment: I added an answer, but it won’t satisfy you.

Answer (score 0):

It’s not easy to ensure, that the domain name is always available, because it’s up to the programmers to define it either in a configuration-file, or as Environment-Variable.

Furthermore, if the application runs in an AWS-container, the configuration is a bit more complicated, because the configuration-file has a different structure.
There is an Nuget-Package available the easy up things, but still not everybody uses it.

So what you want can’t be ensured in a bulletproof way.

If anybody can correct me. I would be quite happy, because I had a similar issue, which I could solve for my own application, but I‘m not glad with my solution yet.